# RoR custom routing/Method/View problem all methods come back as undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, custom-routes

I am playing with custom view and routes.  I think that I have everything right but obviously not.  Essentially I tried to copy the show method and show.html.erb but for some reason it will not work.

My controller

```
    class fatherController < ApplicationController
      def show
        @father = Father.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
         format.html # show.html.erb
         format.xml  { render :xml => @father }
        end
      end

      def ofmine
        @father = Father.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # show.html.erb
          format.xml  { render :xml => @father }
        end
      end
   end
```

My routes.rb

```
Parent::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :fathers do
     resources :kids
  end 

  match 'hospitals/:id/ofmine' => 'father#show2'
end
```

when I go to

> 127.0.0.1:/father/1

it works fine but when I try to go to

> 127.0.0.1:/father/1/ofmine

it gives the following error. It doesn't matter what the variable/method that is called; it occurs at the first one to be displayed. Both show.html.erb and show2.html.erb are the exact same files

### My Error from webserver commandline

```
> Processing by fathersController#show2
> as HTML   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
> Rendered fathers/show2.html.erb within
> layouts/application (31.6ms) Completed
> in 37ms
> 
> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined
> method `name' for nil:NilClass):
>     4:         <td>Name</td><td></td>
>     5:     </tr>
>     6:     <tr>
>     7:  <td><%= @father.name %></td><td></td>
>     8:     </tr>
>     9:     <tr>
>     10:  <td>City</td><td>State</td>   app/views/fathers/show2.html.erb:7:in
> `_app_views_fatherss_show__html_erb___709193087__616989688_0'
```

Error as displayed on actual page

> NoMethodError in Fathers#show2
>
> Showing
>   /var/ruby/chs/app/views/fathers/show2.html.erb
>   where line #7 raised:
>
> undefined method `name' for
>   nil:NilClass
>
> Extracted source (around line #7):
>
> 4:         Name 5:
>    6:      7:  <%=
>   @father.name %> 8:
>    9:      10:
>    CityState

If anyone could tell me what in the world I am doing wrong I would appreciate it greatly.

Here is a copy of my rake routes

```
     father_ofmine      /fathers/:father_id/ofmine(.:format)               {:action=>"show2", :controller=>"fathers"}
     father_kids GET    /fathers/:father_id/kids(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"kids"}
                 POST   /fathers/:father_id/kids(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"kids"}
  new_father_kid GET    /fathers/:father_id/kids/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"kids"}
 edit_father_kid GET    /fathers/:father_id/kids/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"kids"}
      father_kid GET    /fathers/:father_id/kids/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"kids"}
                 PUT    /fathers/:father_id/kids/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"kids"}
                 DELETE /fathers/:father_id/kids/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"kids"}
         fathers GET    /fathers(.:format)                                     {:action=>"index", :controller=>"fathers"}
                 POST   /fathers(.:format)                                     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"fathers"}
      new_father GET    /fathers/new(.:format)                                 {:action=>"new", :controller=>"fathers"}
     edit_father GET    /fathers/:id/edit(.:format)                            {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"fathers"}
          father GET    /fathers/:id(.:format)                                 {:action=>"show", :controller=>"fathers"}
                 PUT    /fathers/:id(.:format)                                 {:action=>"update", :controller=>"fathers"}
                 DELETE /fathers/:id(.:format)                                 {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"fathers"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routes are taken into account according to their order of appearance in your routes file.

I guess `127.0.0.1:/father/1/ofmine` is interpreted as part of `resources :fathers`

Put `match 'hospitals/:id/ofmine' => 'father#show2'` at the top of your routes.rb to try

EDIT 1:

I guess, you made a mistake:

```
# instead of match 'hospitals/:id/ofmine' => 'father#show2' 
match 'father/:id/ofmine' => 'father#show2'
```

And to have a cleaner file, I'd do:

```
Parent::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :fathers do
    match '/ofmine' => 'father#show2'
    resources :kids
  end 
end
```

EDIT 2:

Do you have a show2 method in your controller which gets the variable?

I'm thinking, you're assuming the current ofmine method handles the situation which is wrong

Comment: Ahaa, now I see. So that `match 'father/:id/ofmine' => 'father#show2'` route makes `show2` view render even if there's no action for it. I tested it quickly and it seems to work like that. Without action it's no wonder if `@father` is null.

Comment: right, there is no need to put a method in the controller for the view to be displayed :)

Comment: I have tried it both ways ':controller/:action/:id' and ':controller/:id/:action' and it still doesn't work.  are you saying that I should rename my method of mine to show2?

Comment: right :) '=> 'father#show2' means: go to controller 'father' and fetch method 'show2'

Comment: well looky there.  it was a little more complicated. I had to make my method match my view file and add a route for it as well.  Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @apneadiving +1 for pointing out that the order of the statements in the routes file matters

Answer (score 0):

The error shows up when you try to access `@father`'s name. The problem is that `@father` is null.

Another thing I noticed is that your urls should be in plural, like `/fathers/1`. Run `rake routes` from the command line to see how your routes look like.

Comment: That is a typo on when I was entering the question.  it is actually plural.

Comment: Yes, roger that. I see that you guys are already figuring out the problem.